# Probability and Expected Value of a 3 sided dice rolled 20 times

Tags: probability

You have 20 3-sided dice. You roll all 20, and want to find the product of the number of each of the occurrences.

ie. A shows up 10 times, B 6 times, C 4 times then the value is 240.

I thought that creating an optimal solution of where each occurs 20/3 times would give me a rough estimate, but I am not sure of a better way to approximate the value.

More attempts:

EV= E[X1]*E[X2]*E[20-X1-X2]

And I think we can assume that X1=X2
So this ends up giving me

20*E(X^2)-2*E(X^3)

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in $E[ X_1\cdot \ldots \cdot X_{19} \cdot X_{20}]$, where $X_i$ is the rv which models the face of dice number $i$. 
So, the dices are independent, right?

That gives you:
$$E[ X_1\cdot \ldots \cdot X_{19} \cdot X_{20}]= E[X_1] \cdot \ldots \cdot E[X_20]$$

They are also identically, right? So:
$$E[ X_1\cdot \ldots \cdot X_{19} \cdot X_{20}]= E[X_1]^{20}$$

So let's calculate $E[X_1]$ like you did:
$$ E[X_1]= 1/3 \cdot 1 + 1/3 \cdot 2 + 1/3 \cdot 3=  1/3+2/3+1=2$$

So the expected product of all the faces showing is $2^{20}$.

Comment: Have edited the question as I believe led people astray at first.

Comment: Oh... The product of the number of occurrences is of course something else than what you wrote now. Mhhhh.